# laravel route and controller

Tags: php, laravel

i am a new laravel user and a have admin page which doing update delete and insert my problem is i dont know how to call this functions in route. 
Note: all this options working on one page (admin).

so please can anyone help me ?!

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use DB;
class BlogPostController extends Controller
{ 
/**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(){
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $time = time('H:i:s'); 
        /*$sections = ['History' => 'history.png','Electronics' => 'electronics.png','Electrical' => 'electrical.png','Science' => 'science.png',
                    'Art'=>'ARt.png','Database'=>'database.png','Irrigation'=>'irrigation.png','Novel'=>'Novel.png','Style'=>'Stsyle.png']; 
        */
        $sections = DB ::table('sections')->get();
        return view('libraryViewsContainer.library')->withSections($sections)->withDate($date)->withTime($time);
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create(){
        //return View::make('posts.create');
        return '<center><h1>Creating new section in the library!</h1></center>';
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store( Request $request){
        $section_name = $request->input('section_name');
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $destinationPath = 'images';
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move($destinationPath,$filename);

        DB ::table('sections')->insert(['section_name'=>$section_name,'image_name'=>$filename]);
        return redirect('admin');
    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id){
    //  $post = Post::find($id);

    //      return View::make('posts.show')->with('post', $post);
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id){
    //  $post = Post::find($id);

    //      return View::make('posts.edit')->with('post', $post);
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id,Request $request){

          $section_name = $request->input('section_name');

        DB ::table('sections')->where('id',$id)->update(['section_name'=>$section_name]);
        return redirect('admin');
    }


    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id){
        DB :: table('sections')->where('id',$id)->delete();
        return redirect('admin');
    }

     public function admin()
    {

        $sections = DB ::table('sections')->get();
        return view('libraryViewsContainer.admin',['sections'=>$sections]);
    }

 }
```

Comment: `Route::get('/blog/create', 'BlogPostController@create');` `Route::get('/blog/article/{id}', 'BlogPostController@show');`just to give you an idea

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure of the question, but you list the routes in routes.php, under the web group (so it applies default checks).

When you have resources, they'll use CRUD operations (create, read, update, delete) and will correspond to the default operates in the class. Else, make your own function names, and put seperate routes.

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {

```
    Route::resource('/user', 'UserController');
```

}

Another option is calling the method direct in your routes:

```
    Route::get('/auth/login', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::any('/datafeed/{id}/validate', 'DataFeedController@validateQuery');
```

You'll notice {id} which is the variable available in the function you've selected i.e. function validateQuery($id);

Here's a full example:

```
            class UserController extends BaseController
            {

                public function __construct(User $model)
                {
                    parent::__construct($model);
                }


                /**
                 * Display a listing of the resource.
                 *
                 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
                 */
                public function index()
                {
                    $collection = $this->model->all();
                    return view('user.index')->with('collection', $collection);
                }

                /**
                 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
                 *
                 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
                 */
                public function create()
                {
                    return view('user.create');
                }

                /**
                 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
                 *
                 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
                 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
                 */
                public function store(Request $request)
                {
                    $input = Input::except(['_method', '_token']);
                    $connector = $this->model->create($input);
                    return redirect()->action('UserController@show', [$connector->id]);
                }

                /**
                 * Display the specified resource.
                 *
                 * @param  int  $id
                 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
                 */
                public function show($id)
                {
                    $connector = $this->model->findOrFail($id);
                    return view('user.show')->with('connector', $connector);
                }

                /**
                 * Update the specified resource in storage.
                 *
                 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
                 * @param  int  $id
                 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
                 */
                public function edit($id)
                {
                    $connector = $this->model->findOrFail($id);
                    return view('user.edit')->with('connector', $connector);
                }



                /**
                 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
                 *
                 * @param  int  $id
                 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
                 */
                public function update(Request $request, $id)
                {

                    $input = Input::except(['_method', '_token']);
                    $connector = $this->model->findOrFail($id);
                    $connector->update($input);
                    return redirect()->action('UserController@show', [$id]);

                }


                /**
                 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
                 *
                 * @param  int  $id
                 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
                 */
                public function destroy($id)
                {
                    $currentID = Auth::user();
                    $user = $this->model->findOrFail($id);

                    if ($currentID->id != $user->id) {
                        $user->delete();
                    } else {
                        Session::flash('flash_message', "You cant delete your own account!");
                        Session::flash('flash_type', 'alert-danger');
                    }

                    return redirect()->action('UserController@index');
                }
```

And another example with a custom route:

```
    Route::any('/datafeed/{id}/execute', 'DataFeedController@execute');


        public function execute($id, $test = false) {
            $results = $this->executeQuery($id, $test);
            return view('datafeed.execute')->with('results', $results);

        }
```

Comment: i want to use the function destroy but i dont know how to call it in route Note: function destroy i want to use it in admin page

Comment: <pre><code>
    {!! Form::open([
    'method' => 'DELETE',
    'route' => ['datafeed.destroy', $feed->id],
    'class' => 'no_float no_padding',
    ]) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}

</code></pre>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure on your plans (or even if you've fully read the documentation?) but you can access these functions by doing something similar to the following in your `routes.php` or `Routes\web.php` (depending on your version) file:

`Route::get('/blog/create', 'BlogPostController@create');`

`Route::get('/blog/article/{id}', 'BlogPostController@show');`

The first part is defining the route and the second part is saying what method should be run on the defined controller when this route is matched in the address bar. It doesn't always have to be `get` requests though, you can do `get`, `post`, `patch` and `put`